# Why I got "HTTP error before end of send, stop sending" when post using libCurl

Tags: post, android-ndk, libcurl

I am using the libCurl(7.46) for NDK, when request posting, there is a weird issue about the post content length. When the "CURLINFO_DATA_OUT" exceed some count(1390 bytes get this error, 1333 bytes is OK), I will get the "HTTP error before end of send, stop sending" error.

I am using the curl_formadd to add the post data. What should I do to correct this?

Comment: After investigate the implement of libCurl, this error is happened at http.c,line 3165, and the data->set.httpreq==HTTPREQ_POST_FORM

Answer (score 0):

This is not a libcurl problem: it simply informs you that while you are uploading data, the server returns a HTTP error so libcurl thus stops sending the data.

The problem is thus that the server gives you a HTTP error. Why it does that, we cannot tell based on this little information.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you very much for your reply. I tried libCurl version 7.33 and 7.44, all the same issue. The response code is 504, after send data, the client did not receive any response from server. I think the server side is OK, because our iOS client works correctly, do you have any advices based on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a like issue, but was a deploy to HockeyApp.

```
    100 41.0M    0     0  100 41.0M      0   196k  0:03:34  0:03:34 --:--:--  240k< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://rink.hockeyapp.net http://hockeyapp.net https://hockeyapp.net http://www.hockeyapp.net https://www.hockeyapp.net
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2018 08:50:47 GMT
< Heartbleed: NO; see http://heartbleedheader.com
< Server: nginx
< Set-Cookie: request_method=POST; path=/
< Status: 404 Not Found
< X-Request-Id: aabbccddeeff11223344556677889900
< X-Runtime: 0.037221
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< Content-Length: 32
< Connection: keep-alive
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
{ [32 bytes data]

100 41.0M    0    32  100 41.0M      0   196k  0:03:34  0:03:34 --:--:--  231k
100 41.0M    0    32  100 41.0M      0   196k  0:03:34  0:03:34 --:--:--  205k
* Closing connection 0
{"errors":{"app":["not found"]}}For pattern: /PATH/TO/APK.apk 1 artifacts were found
```

The solution (that worked for me) was regenerate the API token.